# Bottom of the screen is covered in a flashing black

Tags: nvidia, visual-artifacts

For a while now my Ubuntu and for extension Gnome boot-up screen have been having a weird anomaly where about one third of the bottom of the screen has been covered up by black bars that seemingly constantly update. I can't tell what is going on, i tried updating drivers and changing the screen refresh rate and it doesn't disappear. It's not monitor damage it seems because the same issue on the same device disappeared on my windows dual boot when i changed the refresh rate to 30hz.

I have an Nvidia graphics card so i don't really know

I searched the web for an answer and couldn't find anything that worked, any help here would be most thankful!

Comment: Have you tried to change the refresh rate to 30Hz as well? Results? And, of course, if the monitor is supposed to support higher refresh rates for that given resolution and connection type and it shows the same problem in Windows then **definitely** it's an hardware problem.

Comment: no, when i change the refresh rate on Ubuntu the issue persists unlike on windows where it disappears.

Comment: Again, hardware problem.

Comment: really feels like you haven't read what i wrote. quite unhelpful reply that doesn't help to solve the issue.